# variable available for life of form in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, forms, vba, dictionary

I'm trying to create a single array or dictionary object in a user form in excel, and I want the variable/data to be available to other routines during the life of the form.  I've tried using static at the head of the form module, but I can't get this to work.

Does anyone know if this is achievable? The data should be set on form initialisation and won't change whilst the form is open. The data will be referenced on a number of occasions depending on user interaction.

Many thanks

Comment: Will it be referenced outside of the form object itself?

Comment: HI Peter, it will only be referenced by the various controls on the form, and will not be needed outside of it.

Comment: As long as all the processing (including your "other routines") is performed within the context of the form object (i.e. the userform code module), then simply declaring a `Private` dictionary or array at the top of the userform code module is all you need for it to be visible to all routines in the userform. Be sure to initialize it in the constructor (UserForm_Initialize). If your "other routines" are not in the userform code module, then you can add properties to the userform to add, delete, get_keys, etc of a private dictionary object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice guys,

I've managed to find a solution.  I couldn't make the array public in the form object itself, so simply declared it as a public variable in a standard module.

The array is populated during form initialisation and is available whilst the form is in use.

Hope this helps somebody.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Public xyz() As Variant` to the top of your code (replacing xyz with the name of your variable).  This will make the array/dictionary global.

Comment: just note you may need to ditch the `()` depending on the data type (dictionaries use `()` and arrays do not)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I can't declare a public array on a form.  I get a compile error stating: "Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules."